# Having elements upon other elements

Tags: html, css

So I have a header and I'm not really sure how I should code the three element boxes that should be slightly below it, but still on the end of it, like the picture below:

[image]

One way, is perhaps **position absolute and margin-top**, or should I perhaps slice the images, so the top of the boxes is a picture with the header background...

```
.box {
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: -30px;
}
```

Or how should I do it?

Comment: what? i posted this on stackoverflow, or at least i thought...

Comment: Will you put your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please post your code.  Will the blue and red box hover over any content that is below the yellow box?  Or is there space between the yellow box and the content area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time you should post some code of what you've tried. Against my better judgement, I made exactly what you drew.

http://jsfiddle.net/xD69h/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="a">
<span id="a-text">A</span>
<div id="b">
    <span id="b-text">B</span>
</div>
<div id="c">
    <span id="c-text">C</span>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#a {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
background-color: #EFE4B0;
border: 3px solid #FFABCA;
color: #B97A57;
}
#a-text {
float: left;
}
#b {
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #7092BE;
border: 4px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
color: #B97A57;
float: left;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 50px;
}
#c {
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #B97A57;
border: 4px solid #B97A57;
color: white;
float: left;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```